# SQL to_char Currency Formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, currency, to-char

I am facing a `to_char()` currency formatting problem here.

The below code is working for me:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
               'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''
               NLS_CURRENCY = $') "Amount"
  FROM DUAL;
```

which will provide me with the output: `$10,000.00`.
Now, I want to convert the currency into a France currency, which the desire output is `10 000,00` or a Switzerland currency with output `10'000.00`. So, I modified the code as shown below for both of the case above:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
               'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''"", ""''
               NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'' ') "Amount"
  FROM DUAL;


SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
               'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''". "''
               NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'' ') "Amount"
  FROM DUAL;
```

But this code does not work and showing an error of `ORA-12702`. Is there any problem with the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do it in the query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.''''''
           NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'' ') "Amount"
           FROM DUAL;
```

Gives `$10'000.00` (as this string is getting pre-processed there are pairs of quotes around the characters (becoming single) and then to get a single-quote in the string you need four quotes to become one!)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''
           NLS_CURRENCY = ''$'' ') "Amount"
           FROM DUAL;
```

Gives `$10 000,00`

Answer (score 5):

This can be used as well since the decimal notation is already know for French countries

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1000000000,'999,999,999,999.99') "Amount"  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: if value passed in first argument is 0 then output is coming as '.00'. The leading zero is missing. Any fix for that?

Comment: @Ravi.Kumar: Try using "990.99" in the end for trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the options, you can set `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter at a session level:

```
alter session set nls_territory='FRANCE';

select to_char(10000, 'fm99G999D00') as french
  from dual;
```

Result:

```
FRENCH   
----------
10 000,00 


alter session set nls_territory='SWITZERLAND';

select to_char(10000, 'fm99G999D00') as switzerland
  from dual
```

Result:

```
SWITZERLAND
-----------
10'000.00
```

Comment: Good example working fine but when I am using large amount value eg: 124500.21, it returns ##########.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed Simply change format string to fit your largest value. For example `fm999G999D00`